# How to backup SQL Server 2008 database - only the objects, without data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to backup SQL Server 2008 database - only the objects, without data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the Database, Choose Taks, then Generate Scripts.  This allows you to generate a script that will create all objects.

Comment: Note that indexes and other objects are not indexed by default.